# Use "localhost" instead of "app://" to display files in TideSDK

Tags: javascript, filestream, httpserver, tidesdk

Is there any way to load/display files by using 'localhost' address instead of 'app://'?

I mean something like:
http.://localhost/com.app/file.swf

I've tried using  [HTTPServer](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Network.HTTPServer) & [FileStream](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Filesystem.Filestream) listed on TideSDK documentation, but every time I try to load a file, the entire app gets blocked and stops responding.

```
server = Ti.Network.createHTTPServer();

//Specify port number and callback function
//This example can be tested by pointing your
//browser to http://localhost:8082/

server.bind(8082,'localhost',function(request,response) {

//Serve desired file
var contents,
    contentType,
    readFi = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.App.getHome()+'/flash',request.getURI());


if (readFi.exists())
{
   var Stream = Ti.Filesystem.getFileStream(readFi);    
   Stream.open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_READ);     
   contents =Stream.read(); 
   Stream.close();    
}



response.setContentType("application/x-shockwave-flash");

//Setting content length of the response
response.setContentLength(readFi.size());

//Setting status and reason
response.setStatusAndReason('200','OK');

//Finally writing the response back 
response.write(contents);
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried?

Comment: Yes, i've attached it to the main question